# Algoritmo que leia 50 números, calcule e mostre a média aritmética, o maior e menor número

Tags: algoritmo

Sou iniciante em programação e me deparei com um algoritmo que preciso resolver mas não estou conseguindo.

Ler os 50 números usando o "para i de 1 a 50 faca" eu fiz, agora não consigo inserir a média aritmética nisso e muito menos exibir o maior e menor número..

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: c#, java, c, c++? Parece-me linguagens demais

Comment: que tal em python__author__ = 'AndreMart'
numeroInserido = int(input("Digite um n para ele e seus próximos 50 consecutivos n com sua média "))
indice = numeroInserido + 50
acumulador = 0
while numeroInserido < indice:
    acumulador = numeroInserido + 1
    numeroInserido = numeroInserido + 1
acumulador = acumulador / 50
print("Sua média é %d"%acumulador)

Answer (score 5):

A estrutura que faz "para i de 1 a 50 faça"... se chama laço (em inglês, *loop*). É algo praticamente universal na programação e acredito que você deva estar estudando isso por esses dias.

Você já sabe que precisa do laço. A outra coisa que você precisa é de variáveis que irão armazenar os valores que você precisa enquanto seu programa funciona ;)

Vamos precisar de três variáveis para a parte matemática da coisa:

- Uma variável vai armazenar o menor valor encontrado;
- Outra variável vai armazenar o maior valor;
- A terceira variável vai acumular a soma de todos os números do laço. Por que precisamos dela? Porque vamos usar essa soma no algoritmo que obtém a média aritmética :)

Vamos criar essas variáveis:

```
int menor;
int maior;
int soma;
```

Pretendo dar uma resposta que funcione em qualquer uma das linguagens que você tinha marcado originalmente (C#, C++, Java), então vou supor que você já tem um vetor (*array*) com cinquenta números. Um vetor ou *array* é uma estrutura que guarda múltiplos elementos em uma única variável. Vamos chamar nosso vetor de `vetor` e inicializar nossas variáveis:

```
menor = vetor[0];
maior = vetor[0];
soma = 0.0;
```

Note que estamos pegando o "zerésimo" elemento do vetor. É que, em todas essas linguagens, a primeira posição do vetor é a posição 0. Por consequência, se ele tem 50 elementos, a última posição é a 49. Pode parecer estranho, mas é paradigma. Futuramente você vai entender o sentido disso.

Agora, vamos ler os cinquenta números.  Nessas linguagens, um laço pode ser feito com a instrução [`for`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    soma += vetor[i];
    if (vetor[i] < menor) {
        menor = vetor[i];
    }
    if (vetor[i] > maior) {
        maior = vetor[i];
    }
}
```

Note que a linha do `for` tem três comandos entre os parênteses. O primeiro comando é executado uma única vez antes do laço executar. O segundo comando deve retornar um valor booleano e indica se o laço deve continuar ou não - se retornar `true`, o laço continua, senão ele para. O terceiro comando é executado ao final de cada rodada do laço.

E nesse for, `i` é uma variável temporária que usamos para indicar uma posição no vetor. Incrementamos `i` a cada passo para passar para o elemento seguinte.

Note que dentro do laço propriamente dito temos três operações. Estamos alimentando a soma, e também substituindo os valores das variáveis `menor` e `maior` toda vez que encontramos um número menor ou maior do que o que estiver guardado nelas.

Depois que o laço acaba, já temos o menor e o maior elementos nas variáveis que tem esses nomes. Falta só a média aritmética. Essa média é calculada com a seguinte fórmula:

> [(soma de todos os elementos) / (quantidade de elementos)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9dia_aritm%C3%A9tica)

Já temos a soma de todos os elementos na variável soma, então agora só falta:

```
double mediaAritmetica = soma / 50;
```

Só mais uma coisa: variáveis do tipo `int` sempre guardam apenas valores inteiros. Se você tentar guardar um valor não inteiro numa variável do tipo `int`, ou a variável irá descartar a parte não inteira, ou o programa lançará um erro. Já variáveis do tipo `double` são feitas para se trabalhar com números reais, que podem ter partes não inteiras. Foi só por isso que indiquei esse tipo para a média aritmética. A conversão de `int` para `double` em geral é feita de forma automática (mas a recíproca não, ok?).

Boa sorte!

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Foi muito útil!! E desculpe por tantas tags.. Sei que "css" não é linguagem de programação, ela é utilizada em web, certo? Porém, eu precisava colocá-la para poder concluir esse tópico. Me perdoe por isso. rsrs.

Se mais.
Att.
André.

Comment: marque a resposta como certa @André.

Comment: @André CSS é uma tecnologia que você usa para aplicar estilo (negrito, cor de fonte, posicionamento, tamanhos etc.) em elementos de páginas na Internet. Um dia você vai mexer com WEB e vai ter que aprender CSS, mas por enquanto não se preocupe com isso.

Comment: @André Você só precisa colocar **uma** tag pra pergunta ser válida. 5 é o máximo de tags aceitáveis numa pergunta, não o mínimo.

Comment: @mgibsonbr tem razão, o laço ficou grosseiramente errado. Vou ajeitar!